# fetch postgres query result running inside docker through bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, shell, psql

I am running a postgres docker container as below.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                      NAMES
6e3108a980ae        postgres:9.6         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 months ago       Up 10 months               5432/tcp                                   postgres_db_container
```

I run the below command to check the data inside the container.

```
#login into postgres container
docker exec -it postgres_db_container /bin/bash
#getting to psql editor as user DevD. it has no password
psql -U DevD
#getting into airflow database
/dt airflow
#fetching the record from table dag_run
select * from dag_run limit 1;
```

Now I need to create the bash script so that I can cron job this to fetch data every day on particular time

I put the same script in runjob.sh.
and run the command as sh runjob.sh >> result.logs.

However when i run the script it is getting stuck after running the first line.

I am not sure what i am missing.

Comment: When the first line is run, the cron job opens the bash shell inside your container, and it just waits to interact.  There is no provision to accept the subsequent steps of your script.  Does `docker exec -it postgres_db_container psql -U DevD -c "select * from dag_run limit 1;"` give you what you want?  If so, then put that in your script.

Comment: You don't need `docker exec` here, and saving one level of quoting/shell/indirection might help things.  You can just run `psql` directly from the host, connecting to the published port of your container (`docker run -p` option).

Comment: @MikeOrganek Thanks buddy for the help.. it worked